# How to got data from 3 tables Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to make query for my Laravel model. I need all products from subcategories which belongs to parent category with id = 1 and I need also reviews belongs to this products. How can I got it? I tried by Category model:

```
 public function scopeForProduct($query, $id)
{
    $query->where('parent_id', $id)->join('products', 'products.category_id', '=', 'categories.id');
}

public function scopeWithProductPhoto($query)
{
    $query->select('products.*');
}
```

My db: looks like:

```
Categories:
id | parent_id | name | desc
1     0            App   -
2     1          BBQ    subcat of app

Products:
id | category_id | name | description | photo | partner_link
1       2            Item

Reviews:
id | user_id | product_id | description | rating
1       3          1           -           5
```

I need to get all products with reviews from subcategories that belongs for parent category (parent_id = 1 for example).

But It doesn't work.

Comment: Can you add your models or some more information about your db structure? I am not sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Björn edited first post

Answer (score 0):

You can use eloquent relationships for this:
http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships

Product model:

```
public function reviews()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Review');
}

public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Category');
}
```

Category model:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Product');
}
```

Review model:

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Product');
}
```

Query:

```
$parent_id = 1;

$category = Category::with('products.reviews')
whereHas('products', function($q)
{
    $q->has('reviews');
})
->where('parent_id','=',$parent_id);
->get();
```

This only selects the category which has parent_id 1. And also only if it has products with reviews in it. If no products with reviews are there it returns an empty array.

Comment: What if I have more than one category with parent_id 1 will it works too?

Comment: Than you can use: ->whereIn('parent_id', array(1, 2, 3))->get();

Comment: No no I mean if I have more than subcategories with parent_id 1 what then?

Comment: I have problem with this it doesn't return reviews belongs to product.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for you will be `hasManyThrough`:

```
// Category model
public function subProducts()
{
   return $this->hasManyThrough('Product', 'Category', 'parent_id');
}
```

Then you can simply do this:

```
$category = Category::with('subProducts.reviews')->find($id);
$category->subProducts; // Collection of products belonging to $category subcategories
```

This will work for 1-level nested subcategory hierarchy.

Comment: If I var_dump($category) it returns categories and if I var_dump($category->subProducts) i got `object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#185 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(0) { } }`